# How to use the 'exec()' statement on mathematical function using Tkinter-Canvas to create a graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a mathematical graph using the Tkinter-Canvas. This is how it works:
First, the user inputs a mathematical function, just like: y= 5*x + 3.
Then, the program creates a graph on Tkinter-Canvas to show us the function. My Problem is, that I cannot get the y-value of the function.

What I have tried so far is creating a range and set 'x' in the function to the range ocject. It looks like this:

```
yPre=input('Enter function: y = ')
for i in range(-100, 100, 1):
    x=i
```

I've checked out, that:

```
func='3*5+6'
exec('print('+func+')')
```

outputs: 21. So, I just thought: "Now I have to import the module re, replace 'x' with the string of i and that is y. But exec(something) returns  None, not a string. And I'm not able to get the element printed out as a variable.
However, this should be my code:

```
import tkinter as tk, re
# … Canvas, Buttons, Widgets, … 

yPre=input('Enter function: y = ')
for i in range(-100, 100, 1):
    x=i
    yPre=re.sub('x', str(i), yPre)
    y=exec(yPre) # (Or whatever it should be)
```

Comment: Use `eval()` instead of `exec()`.

Comment: What is the difference between `eval()` and `exec()`?

Comment: Documentation for [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) and [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). Pay attention to what they *return*. Neither is something I would recommend to use though.

Comment: One big difference is `eval()` returns the results of evaluating a Python expression, `exec()` always returns `None`. If the expressions will only contain literal constant values like `3.14159`, `5`, and `42`, then I would recommend using `ast.literal_eval()` instead (it's also in the online [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html)), because it's considered "safer".